# lilypond - forcibly write string number under the staff

Tags: lilypond

I am translating a guitar part into lilypond. The string numbers (the ones that show up inside a circle) are showing up on top of the staff.

[image: what it looks like in lilypond]

Is it possible to force lilypond to write them under the staff.... or next to the note head?

[image: what I am aiming for]

Answer (score 5):

In order to place the string numbers below the notes use

`\set stringNumberOrientations = #'(down)`

See [String number indications](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-fretted-strings#string-number-indications) in the Lilypond Notation Reference.

It's also possible to set the number to the right or left of a note. For more information, see [Fingering instructions](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/inside-the-staff#fingering-instructions), specifically the `fingeringOrientations` property.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the string numbers to the right of the note heads use `\set stringNumberOrientations = #'(right)`. This only works for notes in a chord event though, so instead of doing `a2\0` you’d need to do `<a\0>2`.

Side note: Your excerpt strongly looks like Tárrega’s *Recuerdos de la Alhambra*, am I correct? I did type this thing into LilyPond some time ago (although it is missing some cleaning and formatting) because I prepared some notes for playing this on electric bass: https://petzel.at/TARREGA.pdf

Comment: I am considering (not seriously yet.... but the thought has crossed my mind, at least) to sit down to hack lilypond to have a `classical guitar mode` so not to have to write so many quirks to get what we want.... well, I am not there yet in terms of getting what I want _but still_.

Comment: @eftshift0 Will clean it up and provide the ly source the next days. I’m just very busy with work currently.